# Close vote broken?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

What is going on with [this thread](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13885)? 4 people agree with my comment (close vote reason), but only 1 close vote is shown, and I can't vote again. Was the thread closed and re-opened already?

Comment: "Your vote has been recorded." Looks like my close vote worked just fine! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close vote isn't broken -- according the revision history, the post was reopened by 5 community members (6 hours ago at the time of this writing).

Comment: Wow, sorry, didn't realize I could see the close/reopen status in the revision history. Apologies for the dumb question.

Comment: Hey, now you know! :)